# Writing a link cloaking plugin

Tags: php, redirect

I do not want to use any existing plugin. For WordPress-less projects, I would specify a PHP file in `href`

```
<a href="FileOnMySite.php">Click here</a>
```

`FileOnMySite.php` will be like

```
header('Location: http://www.MyaffiliateLink.com')
```

But I'll definitely get `header already sent` in WordPress.

- Is it possible to avoid `header already sent`?
- Any other cloaking method that you know will work best with WordPress?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why the same method can't still work in a WordPress site. If you specifically specify a file to link to that is a valid PHP file, available on your server, then it will still hit that file *instead* of hitting WordPress. If you are having issues with this working, make sure you don't have any rewrite rules interfering in your .htaccess file.